# I lost my private key

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app, lost-wallet

I have BTC in my wallet but I lost my private key and I can't do transactions anymore.
How can I get a new private key or pass the BTC to another address?

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have the private key, there is no way to access those coins.  Period.  The security of Bitcoin as a currency relies on that fact.

Either recover the private key somehow, or consider the coins gone.