# If I have the hard drive that I mined bitcoins on, can I find the wallet?

Tags: wallet, lost-bitcoins, lost-wallet

I used to mine bitcoins years ago and I still have the hard drive. I just don't know where to find the wallet or the key or any of it.

Is there any way for me to do that?

Comment: Have you tried searching for a file named wallet.dat on the hard drive? It should be in <drive letter>\Documents and Settings\<user name>\Application data\Bitcoin or <drive letter>\Users\<user name>\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin

Comment: @NickODell: I think that could be an answer. related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/49496/5406